# perl value in 'range' of random array

Tags: perl

I'm having the next problem, I have some random values in one array and I want to print a message if one of those values in array matches my variable. 
Example:

```
my @random_pool = (1, 30, 13, 40, 58, 7);
my $value = 17;
```

Want I want to do is:

```
if($value in @random_pool) {
   print "match";
} else {
   print "not mach";
```

Also would a solution be possible if there wasn't an array but a string?

Example:

```
my $random_pool = "1, 30, 13, 40, 58, 7";
my $value = 17;

if($value in $random_pool) {
   print "match";
} else {
   print "not mach";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (grep { $_ == $value } @array) {
    print "match\n";
} else {
    print "not match\n";
}
```

`grep { $_ eq $value } @array` is more appropriate when you are matching strings.

For large lists, and if `$value` is not `undef`, `List::Util::first` is more efficient because it won't necessarily have to search through the whole list:

```
use List::Util 'first';
if (defined( first { $_ == $value } @array )) { ... }
```

But my go to quick-and-dirty search is to stringify the array and search for the value with a regex.

```
if (" @array " =~ / $value /) { ... }
```

(It's dirty because it might not work for edge cases like `@array` having elements with spaces in them or `$value` having regex metacharacters)

Answer (score 8):

I'd use map to create a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my @random_pool = (1, 30, 13, 40, 58, 7);

my %is_in_pool = map { $_ => 1 } @random_pool;

my $value = 17;

print "Match\n" if $is_in_pool{$value};
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can reuse the hash if you want to iterate with different values - `map` iterates your array once, where something like `grep` needs to iterate each time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It Works! But for me its more simple to use the method provided by Mob! Thank you for your time

Comment: @rooger Note that [there are significant performace differences in the solutions](https://gist.github.com/haukex/62233ecc427b8c0e96ba011ddefd11e0) depending on the number of lookups you are doing and the size of the array.